# How to remove a search domain by name from the resolver in dnspython?

Tags: python-3.x, dns, dnspython

I'm using [dnspython](http://www.dnspython.org/) to conduct DNS queries. Since my machine is joined to my company's domain, the corporate domain is part of my search domains. However, I `NEVER` want that domain to be appended when I am doing forward lookups on hostnames.

An approach that I've taken to remove unwanted nameservers by value is the following:

```
import dns.resolver

my_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
my_resolver.nameservers.remove('172.20.10.1')
```

Unfortunately, I cannot take the same approach( or I don't know how) with for `my_resolver.search` because its elements are `<class 'dns.name.Name'>` instances and not strings.

Since my corporate domain seems to be the last element in `my_resolver.search` I remove it like so: `del my_resolver.search[-1]`. But I want to remove it by value, how can I do so, preferably without iterating through `my_resolver.search`.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I want to remove it by value, how can I do so, preferably without iterating through my_resolver.search

Just create a `dns.name.Name` from the string you have.

For example:

```
import dns.name
import dns.resolver

my_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()

name_to_remove = 'example.com'
name = dns.name.from_text(name_to_remove)
my_resolver.search.remove(name)
```

You could also use `dns.query.udp()` and other related functions instead of `dns.resolver.Resolver.query()`. Then if you really need search names you can manually add whatever search names you want in a for loop, for example. That's exactly how they do it in the Resolver class (see https://github.com/rthalley/dnspython/blob/57d38840f3cb59b838e49fe65caa6062a0904832/dns/resolver.py#L892).

Comment: Couldn't one also use the `dns.resolver.Resolver.resolve()` function with search=None (default) or search=False ?

https://dnspython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolver-class.html#dns.resolver.Resolver.resolve